# the execution time in this method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i'm a newbie in ASP.NET so i have a code that i need to  optimize it and make it faster because it takes a very long time to be excuted .
this part where it takes time :

```
 public bool IsAuthenticated(String domain, String username, String pwd)
    {
        img = null;
        String domainAndUsername = domain + @"\" + username;
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(_path, domainAndUsername, pwd);

        try
        {//Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication.

            Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();

            if (null == result)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //Update the new path to the user in the directory.
            _path = result.Path;
            if (result.Properties["cn"].Count > 0)
           _userName = _filterAttribute = (String)result.Properties["cn"][0];

            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Please Helps !!!

Comment: I cant understand what is it that take time with this. I could only conclude that `DirectorySearcher` is not a db and that is what take time. you have to move this to a database or let us have a lool at `DirectorySearcher` and see what we could do.

Comment: You need to find out how `DirectorySearcher` works internally. Suppose it does request to domain controller, i.e. it is time-consuming I/O operation similar to request to DB.

Comment: Please edit and add details. How long is it taking? How long do you want it to take? Are you behind a proxy etc

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate, I recommend use PrincipalContext instead.

(This code is in production)

```
namespace Contoso.Security
{

    internal class LDAPService : ILDAPService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<LDAPService> _logger;
        public LDAPService(ILogger<LDAPService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public bool ValidateCredentials(string domain, string user, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                using PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, "ou=ADAM Users,O=Microsoft,C=US");
                return domainContext.ValidateCredentials(user, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogCritical(ex,ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```